# Nested Macro not expanding correctly

Tags: rust, macros

I am trying to nest macro calls to ease converting between rust and c ffi types.

The inner macro generates calls to conversion functions from type names like this:

```
macro_rules! type_conversion {
    ($arg_name:ident, bool, BOOL) => (crate::type_wrappers::type_conversion::convert_rust_bool($arg_name));
    ($arg_name:ident, BOOL, bool) => (crate::type_wrappers::type_conversion::convert_c_bool($arg_name));
}
```

The outer macro now uses this to generate further conversions.
It basically works like this:

```
macro_rules! outer {
    ($arg_name:ident, $type1:ty, $type2:ty) => (type_conversion!($arg_name, $type1, $type2));
}
```

Now, when i try to use the outer macro like this:

```
fn outer() {
    outer!(hello_world, bool, BOOL);
}
```

I get this Error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `bool`
   --> src\type_wrappers\type_conversion.rs:252:77
    |
202 | macro_rules! type_conversion {
    | ---------------------------- when calling this macro
...
252 |     ($arg_name:ident, $type1:ty, $type2:ty) => (type_conversion!($arg_name, $type1, $type2));
    |                                                                             ^^^^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
...
256 |     outer!(hello_world, bool, BOOL);
    |     ------------------------------- in this macro invocation
```

I cannot make sense out of this error, especially since CLions Macro expansion tool expands this into:

```
type_conversion!(hello_world , bool , BOOL )
```

Which is what i would expect and also, what the Error suggests.

Where is the Error in those Macros?

Comment: @Kitsu Ah,````test!```` was meant to be ````outer!````. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `ty` macro type cannot be casted to identifier (which `bool` & `BOOL` parameter are) and thus matched. So with `ident` type it works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c65a54bc973df544f9689d2857737c4)):

```rust
macro_rules! outer {
    ($arg_name:ident, $type1:ident, $type2:ident) => {
        type_conversion!($arg_name, $type1, $type2)
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem, after reading the specification of ````ty```` again, it became more clear